# Need to set part of my PS string as a variable so when it runs it asks for the value

Tags: sql, powershell, variables, cmd, exe

I have tried using the below however what I am trying to achieve is being able to pass this through PowerShell and it asking me for a value for `-companyCode`.

```
"\Program Files (x86)\Home\Business Intelligence\ScriptoSql\"ScriptoSqldb1.exe -companyCode="" -sqlserver=SQLSERVER1\INS1,8071 -sqldatabase=StagingDB
```

Now the command works if I pass a value with it in the string but I want to make it dynamic so when it is called it will ask for that value and it is then entered by the user and the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the command invocation in a custom function with a [mandatory parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-3.0) `-CompanyCode`. That way PowerShell will prompt for a missing parameter when the function is called.

```
function Invoke-ScriptToSqlDB {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$CompanyCode
    )

    & "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\...\ScriptoSqldb1.exe" -companyCode=$CompanyCode ...
}

Invoke-ScriptToSqlDB -CompanyCode 'whatever'     # pass company code
Invoke-ScriptToSqlDB                             # prompt for company code
```

Comment: I'm passing that through however I get an error

The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString